# square_root very large number in C until < 1000

Tags: php, c

I have a very large number:

```
char *big_numbr_str = "4325242066733762057192832260226492766115114212292022277";
```

I want to keep square-rooting this number until it's < 1000. In PHP, I can do this relatively easily:

```
while($num > 1000):
    $num = sqrt($num);
endwhile;

$num = floor($num);
```

I'm now trying to achieve the same in C, to end with the same result. For reference, after 5 cycles in the while loop, the end result in PHP from the above snippet + starting number is 50; If you square-root this number 5 times anywhere else you should get a similar result, rounded down.

How would I achieve the same in plain C? Seems storing a number of this size is more complex in C than expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need a big number library to handle numbers like this.    On Linux, you can try [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

Alternately, you can write your own bigint routine and implement square root manually.  This will take some time to implement properly, as you basically have to do all the math by hand a digit at a time.  It can be done (I've done it), but it won't be "simple".

Comment: Could that "relatively simple" math of square-rooting be done with the number stored in a char?

Comment: Yes, you can: take the left half of the string, and make some corrections. repeat until the remaining part is < 1000 (< 4 charcters)

Comment: Seems to work with GMP, thanks! Although I'd still be interested to hear if there's a raw C approach without linking GMP.

Comment: @Tiago You could try to use something like what is shown [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/512358).  There technically _is_ a way to calculate the square root digit by digit.

Answer (score 0):

In order to store such a large integer (`4325242066733762057192832260226492766115114212292022277`) you can use `array of integers`, store a single digit per element. The array should act like a single integer. Write the routines to do the computation (like the way you would do in a piece of paper).

Alternatively, google [bignum c](https://www.google.ca/#q=bignum+in+c), and see if you can find any library that implements large integer arithmetic. Take a look at [bignum.c](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~skiena/392/programs/bignum.c) by Steven Skiena, libraries like [MPFR](http://www.mpfr.org/) and [MPIR](http://mpir.org).